# React Native Functional Components - undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am practicing moving from class components to functional components in react native and I am having trouble understanding how to access navigation from a component. Normally I would run something like `this.props.navigation.navigate('screen')`. Now I am normally passing `navigation` as a prop.

But it doesn't seem to work in the following example. Where am I going wrong? I am using react-navigation:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Form, Input, Item, Button, Label } from "native-base";

import * as firebase from "firebase";

const LoginForm = ({navigation}) => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  
    const addEmail = (email) => {
      setEmail(email)
    }
  
    const addPassword = (password) => {
      setPassword(password)
    }

    return (
        <Form>
            <Item floatingLabel>
                <Label>Email</Label>
                <Input
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    onChangeText={(email)=>addEmail(email)}
                />
            </Item>
            <Item floatingLabel>
                <Label>Password</Label>
                <Input
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    onChangeText={(password)=>addPassword(password)}
                />
            </Item>
            <Button style={{ margin: 10 }}
                full
                rounded
                success
                onPress={()=>handleLogin(email, password, navigation)}
            >
                <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Login</Text>
            </Button>
        </Form>
    );
};

export default LoginForm;





const handleLogin = (email, password, navigation) => {
    console.log(email, password)
    firebase.auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password)
    .then(() => {firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified ? navigation.navigate('Home') : navigation.navigate('StartScreen')})
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
         
  }
```

I create a stack navigator in App.js

```
const bottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Ionicons  name="ios-home" size={25} color={tintColor}/>
          // <Icon name="qrcode" size={25} color={tintColor} />
        )
      }
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          // <Icon name="search" size={25} color={tintColor} />
          <Ionicons  name="md-person" size={25} color={tintColor}/>
        )
      }
    },


  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#eb6e3d'
    }
  }
);






const RootSwitch = createSwitchNavigator({ 
  StartScreen,
  Signup,
  Login,
  bottomTabNavigator
  });

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootSwitch);
```

Comment: are you creating your stackNavigator? the route file.

Comment: I use createBottomNavigator in combination with react-navigation components.

Comment: you use `navigation.navigate('StartScreen')`, but your screen name is `Profile`.

Comment: Upon proper authentication the navigation route is `Home`. The error here is on accessing navigation. This setup works perfectly with class components.

Comment: can u show the error?

Comment: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')`

Comment: i edit my answer, check it please.

Comment: is there a reason why you are using the `navigation` object outside of your component? In other words: why is `handleLogin` declared outside of the `LoginForm` component?

Answer (score 0):

try using hooks, like this:

```js
//add this import
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';

//change function to callback
const handleLogin = useCallback(async(email,password,navigation) => {
    console.log(email, password)
    
    await firebase.auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password)
    .then(() => {firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified ? navigation.navigate('Home') : navigation.navigate('StartScreen')})
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}, []);
```